# How to tell cmake/cpack (NSIS) to deploy the required libs?

Tags: qt, cmake, nsis, mingw32

my program compiles and runs fine under Linux. Cross-compiling it for Windows also is no problem. But now I would like to tell CPack, that it should include all required libs (dlls) into the (NSIS) setup file.

For the Qt libs, I was successful:

```
IF (WIN32)
    INSTALL(FILES ${QT_LIBRARY_DIR}/libQtCore4.dll.a
                  ${QT_LIBRARY_DIR}/libQtGui4.dll.a
            DESTINATION bin)
ENDIF (WIN32)
```

But I don't know how to achieve this for, e.g., the libgcc, libstdc++ (without hard-coding the paths). Any hints on how to do this (using CMake 2.8.8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode paths, then you should write your own CMake module, which finds those libraries and sets variables for you. Check out [CMake Wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aHow_To_Find_Libraries).

Comment: The above page linked above now is hosted at <https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries>.

Answer (score 2):

With newer CMake (>= 3.21), you can use the option `RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` to automatically detect which dll to copy (note that you must install not only the compiled target, but also the compiled subtargets, for CPack to work properly):

```
install(TARGETS ${SubTarget} 
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_NAME_MAIN}
    RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
        PRE_EXCLUDE_REGEXES "api-ms-" "ext-ms-" "hvsifiletrust" "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin.*" ".*/msys64/mingw64/bin.*"
        POST_EXCLUDE_REGEXES ".*system32/.*\\.dll" ".*/msys64/mingw64/bin.*"
        DIRECTORIES $ENV{QT_DIR}/lib $ENV{QT_DIR}/bin ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    )
```

Note that you do not want all the dll, and you can skip some (the system32 ones, the api-ms which are irrelevant, etc.).

Some other files/directories might also be needed:

```
if(lib_name MATCHES "Qt.*::.*")
    string(REPLACE "::" "" lib_name ${lib_name}) 
    if (WIN32)
        install(FILES $ENV{QT_DIR}/bin/${lib_name}${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} 
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR} COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_NAME_MAIN})
    else()
        install(FILES $ENV{QT_DIR}/lib/lib${lib_name}${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} 
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_NAME_MAIN})
    endif()
    install(DIRECTORY $ENV{QT_DIR}/plugins/platforms/ DESTINATION ./platforms 
        COMPONENT ${COMPONENT_NAME_MAIN})
endif()
```